# How can I get an instance of the Cesium viewer from document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, getelementbyid, cesiumjs

I have tried using

`var viewer = document.getElementById("cesiumContainer")`

but this doesn't return the actual viewer object. What's the correct approach to get an instance of/reference to the viewer that's been created already. I'm trying to get access to it in a part of my code that is out of scope with the part where I created the viewer, if that wasn't obvious.

The viewer is being created using the `resium` package for a react app with `<Viewer>`. The HTML page that renders still wraps the viewer in a div with the id `cesiumContainer` and from inspecting the source in dev tools it looks the same as it would without react, so I would think it would behave the same in terms of being able to access it. Of course that may not be the case.

Comment: How was `Cesium.Viewer` instantiated?

Comment: It's been made in a react app using the `resium` package. I'm hoping to access it directly in a different react component (displayed on the same page, so same DOM) without having to messily pass around the reference in props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer focuses on your use of Resium, Cesium and class based React Components.

If you are using React 16+ you can use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to achieve your goal.

1. First create a context that will be used as your singleton reference. The state and React Context are exported.

CesiumContext.js

```
export const state = {viewer: '', setInstance: (ref)=>{state.viewer = ref;}};
export default CesiumContext;
```

2. In every component you want to have a reference to the Cesium instance, set the class property `contextType` to the React Contact reference. (`CesiumContext`). In the ViewerComponent constructor use `createRef()`. It will capture the only prop (`ref`) that will allow the Context state to be set, thereby allowing all other components access to the reference. Note the use of `componentDidMount()` to set the state of the context to there reference provided by Resium.

ViewerComponent.js

```
export default class ViewerComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.ref.current && this.ref.current.cesiumElement) {
      this.context.setInstance(this.ref.current.cesiumElement);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <Viewer ref={this.ref}/>
  }
}
ViewerComponent.contextType = CesiumContext;
```

3. In the App component, render the ContextProvider with the state of the context. Once the `ViewComponent` renders/mounts, and the Context state is set, then every Child component under the Context element has access to the current Cesium View object. There is a problem created by this structure in that in order for this to happen, the tree must be rerendered. Based upon your app you may have to force the rerendering.

App.js

```
      <div className="App">
        <CesiumContext.Provider value={state}>
          <ViewerComponent/>
          <AComponent/>
          <BComponent/>
        </CesiumContext.Provider>
      </div>
```

4. Finally, in any components requiring access to the shared resource (Cesium View instance in this case), set `contextType` on the class. In the `componentDidMount` grab the instance from the context.

Any Component

```
export default class AComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.viewer = false;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.viewer = this.context.viewer;
  }
  render() {
    return <p>{/* do something with this.viewer */}</p>;
  }
}
AComponent.contextType = CesiumContext;
```

A complete solution demonstrates this below. One component `AComponent` accesses the [Cesium.View.shadowed](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Viewer.html#shadows) property and 'BComponent` accesses the [Cesium.View. allowDataSourcesToSuspendAnimation](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Viewer.html#allowDataSourcesToSuspendAnimation) property.

[React Playground Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/resium-cesium-context-kjil8?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

The docs indicate that if you import `useCesium` from `resium` then the following code will grab the reference you are after.

```js
import { Viewer } from "cesium";
import { useCesium } from "resium";
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const { viewer } = useCesium();
  return <p>Cesium Viewer object is{viewer ? "" : " not"} provided here.</p>;
};
export default ExampleComponent;
```

[Reference](https://resium.darwineducation.com/advanced#get-cesium-context-with-your-component)

Edit: using Class based components requires accessing the instance differently. Here are two samples from the documentation:

Using a class method:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Viewer as CesiumViewer } from "cesium";
import { Viewer } from "resium";
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  private viewer: CesiumViewer | undefined;
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.viewer) {
      // this.viewer is Cesium's Viewer
      // DO SOMETHING
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Viewer
        ref={e => {
          this.viewer = e ? e.cesiumElement : undefined;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Using createRef:

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import { Viewer as CesiumViewer } from "cesium";
import { Viewer } from "resium";
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  private ref = createRef<CesiumViewer | undefined>();
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.ref.current?.cesiumElement) {
      // this.ref.current.cesiumElement is Cesium's Viewer
      // DO SOMETHING
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <Viewer ref={this.ref} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that! So it looks like in order to use this I would need to refactor to functional components or do some other sort of workaround to use a hook in a class component...

Comment: `useCesium` is a hook, per those docs. Trying to use it in a class component threw an error. I did find this workaround (https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/how-to-use-react-hooks-in-class-components) which I can go with if my team doesn't agree to refactoring :P

Comment: Hooks are used in functional components - not class based components. I'm not sure what you want to accomplish. But I hope you consider upvoting and accepting this answer.

Comment: I want to get a reference to the viewer object outside of the component where it was created.

Comment: I commented before your comment showed up. searching...

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm using to access it inside the component that renders the viewer. However, I'm trying to access the viewer object in 'cousin' components. I've tried elevating it as a state variable in the parent and sending it up with a callback and down again to a cousin with props, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm starting to think this implementation just isn't possible.

Comment: Bummer. Sorry this hasn't done it for you. Hope you find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the effort!

Comment: I'm thinking Context would work, and was going to put a repl together, but no time. You could acknowledge the effort with an up vote.